# Play Framework 2.1 - Render List<SqlRow> parameters

Tags: playframework-2.1

I use Play FrameWork 2.1 
I have a variable List list in controller. How to I can render it to view and how to use?

```
SqlQuery query = Ebean.createSqlQuery("select * from users");<br/>
List<SqlRow> list = query.findList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The example provided below, is based on one of the provided with the framework (Zentasks)
(See: java/zentasks/app/views/project/group.scala.html for full example)

The interesting part of the mentioned example is how to pass a list to a view and how to iterate it:

```
@(projects: List[Project]) // Pass a list of Project to the view, use list instead of project in your case
<ul>
    @projects.map { project =>      // Iterates the list
        @views.html.projects.item(project)
    }
</ul>
```

Hope that helps.